# Package-lock json file modified without any dependency installation when npm install executed

Tags: npm, npm-install

currently I have an issue.
when I run the command `npm install`, the `package-lock.json` is executed unexpected formatting.

As you can see below, the `requires` property is deleted after running `npm install`. Even no any package installation

for example from this:

```
 "@react-native-community/masked-view": {
      "version": "0.1.10",
      "resolved": "foo",
      "integrity": "bar",
      "requires": {}
    },
```

to this:

```
  "@react-native-community/masked-view": {
      "version": "0.1.10",
      "resolved": "foo",
      "integrity": "bar"
    },
```

However, this is not my wanted action, and because of it, every commit between me a colleague has difference.

I would like this `auto formatting...?` won't work when I run `npm install`

Can anyone has an idea about this issue?

This is my `.npmrc`

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

npm version: v8.4.0

node version: v14.17.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the next command instead:

```
npm ci
```

which does the following:

> This command is similar to npm install, except it's meant to be used in automated environments such as test platforms, continuous integration, and deployment -- or any situation where you want to make sure you're doing a clean install of your dependencies (It will never write to package.json or any of the package-locks: installs are essentially frozen).

For more information look up the **ci** command in the npm documentation.